# Demonstrate rhombus diagonals are orthogonals

Tags: vector-spaces

I need to demonstrate that the diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular to each other, with the orthogonality.
I first try to find the norms of that vectors but i realized that it change nothing.
Secondly, i try to find coordinates of the diagonals but how can i do that ?

Comment: What is the definition of a "diamond"?

Comment: @coffeemath sorry a rhombus

Comment: Let $a$ and $b$ be the sides of the rhombus. Just take the dot product of the two diagonal, i.e., $a+b$ and $a-b$.

Comment: why _a - b_ give a digonal ?

Comment: i understood prefectly thank's